# Difficulty in Achieving Design on [FIGMA SCREENSHOT] – SVG Waves Not Adapting to Container Item 2 size

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, web-frontend

Hello Stack Overflow community,
I'm a designer, Just started studying HTML and CSS.
I'm working on implementing a specific design for a webpage, and I'm encountering an issue with the SVG waves not adapting to the size of the container item 2. I'm trying to achieve [describe the design or share the URL where the design is implemented], but it seems that the SVG is not adjusting its size correctly.

I've ensured that both the .container-item-2 and #waves have height: 100%; in the CSS, and the design works well on larger screens. However, on smaller screens or different devices, the SVG does not adjust as expected.
[design login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7dya.png)
[page in development](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngesD.png)
P.S.: I'll edit later and post the github of project. I still need to learn to do it, and I'm doing now hahaha

Comment: "I'm trying to achieve [describe the design or share the URL where the design is implemented]"? Have you copy-pasted a template of question or something?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I speak portuguese, so I ask ChatGPT to translate my question hahahahaha and forgot to edit it hahahaha